# Item ID to collection

Tags: blueprism

I am trying save all the completed items, not item ids rather item id data associated with it  in queue to a collection. I tried ' Get item data' Action under work queue VBO but I'm getting only one record into collection and when I'm trying to loop it it replacing the earlier record. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Get Report Data` action in the `Work Queues` internal VBO and set its parameter `Include Completed Items?` (flag) to `True`.

Loop over the resulting `Item IDs` collection and use `Get Item ID` action (the one you're using now) to output each of the Item Data collections to your required data destination.